# How to properly implement backend ReactiveList in RxUI to avoid thread affinity issue?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, system.reactive, reactiveui

I'm new to Rx.Net & RxUI. During my learning of these two libraries, I tried to build a demo application which extracts images from websites. I used WPF combined with Rx.Net and RxUI to build the Views and ViewModels, and HtmlAgilityPack to handle html documents. My code looks like below

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var canSearch =
            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.TargetUrl, targetWebSite => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetWebSite));
        _searchCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(GetHtmlDocument, canSearch);
        _imageSequence = _searchCommand
            .SelectMany(ImageExtractService.ExtractAllImageAddress).Distinct().Publish().RefCount();
        _imageSequence.Subscribe(
            url => ImageList.Add(new ScrappedWebImageViewModel { ImageUrl = url }),
            ex => this.Log().Error(ex)); //Causing problem, need better solution
    }

    private readonly IObservable<string> _imageSequence;

    private IHtmlDownloadService _htmlDownloadService;

    private IHtmlDownloadService HtmlDownloadService =>
        _htmlDownloadService ?? (_htmlDownloadService = Locator.Current.GetService<IHtmlDownloadService>());

    private IImageExtractService _imageExtractService;

    private IImageExtractService ImageExtractService =>
        _imageExtractService ?? (_imageExtractService = Locator.Current.GetService<IImageExtractService>());

    public ReactiveList<ScrappedWebImageViewModel> ImageList =
        new ReactiveList<ScrappedWebImageViewModel>();

    private readonly ReactiveCommand<Unit, HtmlDocument> _searchCommand;

    public ICommand SearchCommand => _searchCommand;

    private async Task<HtmlDocument> GetHtmlDocument()
    {
        return await HtmlDownloadService.GetHtmlDocument(TargetUrl);
    }
}
```

View:

```
public partial class MainWindow : IViewFor<MainViewModel>
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
        this.WhenActivated(d => 
        {
            d(this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.Status, x => x.TblStatus.Text));
            d(this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.Progress, x => x.TblProgress.Text));
            d(this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.TargetUrl, x => x.TbxTargetWebSite.Text));
            d(this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.ImageList, x => x.LbxImageList.ItemsSource));
            d(this.BindCommand(ViewModel, x => x.SearchCommand, x => x.BtnBeginSearch));
        });
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof(MainViewModel), typeof(MainWindow));

    public MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get => (MainViewModel) GetValue(ViewModelProperty);
        set => SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);
    }

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get => ViewModel;
        set => ViewModel = (MainViewModel)value;
    }
}
```

HtmlDownloadService:

```
internal class HtmlDownloadService : IHtmlDownloadService
{
    private readonly HtmlWeb _webClient = new HtmlWeb();

    public async Task<HtmlDocument> GetHtmlDocument(string url)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => _webClient.Load(url));
    }
}
```

ImageExtractService:

```
internal class ImageExtractService : IImageExtractService
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ExtractAllImageAddress(HtmlDocument doc)
    {
        const string mstring = @".+\.(jpg|png|ico|jpeg|bmp|tif)$";
        var hrefList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@".//*[@href]");
        var srcList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@".//*[@src]");
        if (hrefList != null)
        {
            foreach (var href in hrefList)
            {
                var attr = href.Attributes["href"];
                if (Regex.IsMatch(attr.Value, mstring))
                {
                    yield return attr.Value;
                }
            }
        }

        if (srcList == null) yield break;
        foreach (var src in srcList)
        {
            var attr = src.Attributes["src"];
            if (Regex.IsMatch(attr.Value, mstring))
            {
                yield return attr.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, right after the command is executed, the application will halt. At this moment the main thread is running in

> System.Reactive.dll!System.Reactive.Concurrency.AsyncLock.Wait

However no exception is thrown, and the application will exit if allowed to proceed. I tried to quote/unquote several lines, and it seems this is just another instance of the 'thread affinity' issue. But I don't know how fix this problem. My questions in short is:

1. How to update the VM in the most appropriate way?
2. How to catch the exception that shut down the application?

Update:

I tried with some other methods without the observables

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    var canSearch =
        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.TargetUrl, targetWebSite => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetWebSite));
    SearchCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(SearchImageAsync, canSearch, ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance);
}
```

and

```
private async Task SearchImageAsync()
{
    var doc = await HtmlDownloadService.GetHtmlDocument(TargetUrl);
    var imgs = ImageExtractService.ExtractAllImageAddress(doc);
    foreach (var url in imgs)
    {
        ImageList.Add(new ScrappedWebImageViewModel {ImageUrl = url});
    }
}
```

But still can't solve it. I'm using the latest unstable(alpha/preview) version of Rx.Net & RxUI, and there is little sample code for me to get started. So if anyone could provide some it would be a huge help, thanks!

Comment: The `.Distinct().Publish().RefCount()` combination is a bit weird. Why are you using that?

Comment: `.Distinct()` is used to remove duplicated items, and `.Publish().RefCount()` is used to create a hot observable. I don't think they are causing the trouble, since I tried another approach without them and still no luck.

Comment: So if the user initiates a second search and the same HTML document is loaded then the `.Distinct()` will filter out all of the extracted images as they were produced the first time. That seems odd to me, but is that what you want?

Comment: And using `.Publish().RefCount()` will make your observable be a run once observable - if it completes or errors then any subsequent subscriptions won't restart the observable. You need to ensure that you don't have any errors in your sequence.

Comment: Well actually I came across some websites who use the same image many times, and the `.Distinct()` is used to handle that. Each time the command is triggered the list will be cleared, I just didn't include that part of code. Also I edited my question to include a new approach :)

Comment: So you're loading a new document each time. Just remember that `.Distinct()` requires keeping all of the values in memory for this to work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
_imageSequence.Subscribe(
```

to

```
_imageSequence.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).Subscribe(
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still got the same outcome, and strangely the `.ObserveOn()` operator somehow requires assembly `System.Windows.Forms`, I wonder if this is intended?

Comment: I managed to catch the exception, and it suggests that I should provide the view location for the ViewModel of list items. Looks like I need to get a thorough study of the manual. Thank you sir, and if you know any up-to-date demo please tell me, that would be really helpful!

Comment: it shouldn't require Forms to pull in. Something else strange must be bringing it in.